bold math in minipage environment
I looked at all questions and answers on bold math, but could not find an answer to my question.
I have this code, in which the Oplus symbol in the second column comes out bold, as it should. The top matrix in the 3rd column also comes out bold, but not as bold as the Oplus. And I could not make the bottom matrix in the 3rd column bold.
My question is how do I make both matrices in the 3rd column as bold as the Oplus symbol? Unfortunately, the current code also does not compile. It does compile in my big latex file, but that latex file has so many preambles that I don't know which ones are needed.
I am not a big latex expert, so I hope someone can help with this.
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsthm, amsmath}

\usepackage{tabularx}  

\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}


\makeatletter

\newcommand{\leqnomode}{\tagsleft@true}

\newcommand{\reqnomode}{\tagsleft@false}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}
    \begin{center} 
        \begin{minipage}{0.15\linewidth}   
            \leqnomode
            \begin{equation} \nonumber 
                    \begin{split}
                    \bpx \ti & \ti & \ti  \\ 
                    \ti & \ti & \ti  \\
                    \ti & \ti & \ti  \epx & \ti \\ 
                    \bpx \ti & \ti & \ti  \\ 
                    \ti & \ti & \ti  \\
                    \ti & \ti & \ti  \epx & \ti      
                \end{split} 
            \end{equation}
        \end{minipage}  
        \begin{minipage}{0.05 \linewidth}
            $ \;\;\; \longrightarrow  $ 
        \end{minipage}
        \begin{minipage}{0.15\linewidth}   
            \leqnomode
            \begin{equation} \nonumber 
                        \begin{split}
                    \left( \!\!  \Oplus \!\! \right) &  0  \\
                    \bpx \ti & \ti & \ti  \\ 
                    \ti & \ti & \ti  \\
                    \ti & \ti & \ti  \epx & \ti          
                \end{split} 
            \end{equation}
        \end{minipage}  
        \begin{minipage}{0.05 \linewidth}
            $ \;\;\; \longrightarrow  $ 
        \end{minipage}
        \begin{minipage}{0.15\linewidth}   
            \leqnomode
            \boldmath   \begin{equation} \nonumber 
                %\hspace{-3cm} 
                \begin{split}
                    \!\!\!\!\!\!\!   \bpx[c|cc] \Lambda_1 & 0 & 0  \\ \hline 
                    0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
                    0 & 0 & 0 \epx  & 0 \\ 
                    \bpx[c|cc] \ti & \ti & \ti  \\ \hline 
                    \ti & \ti & \ti  \\
                    \ti & \ti & \ti  \epx & \ti 
                \end{split} 
            \end{equation}
        \end{minipage}  
    \end{center} 
    \caption{Bla}  
    \label{bla} 
\end{figure}

\end{document} 


Unfortunately your code does not compile without error. Please correct the errors in the shown code. See also I've just been asked to write a minimal working example (MWE), what is that?

What are \bpx, \epx and \ti? Besides, split allows just one & and you probably want matrix.

This cannot compile in any project, unless you have redefined split.
